# Connect to third-party two-way https ws from glassfish behind ssl-terminating-point

Tags: ssl, iis, glassfish, f5

## Context

I developed an application deployed in a Glassfish 3.1. This application is accessed only by https and sometimes it must connect to third-party webservices located out the customers networks. The customer have other applications inside his network; mine is only a new one "service".

### Topology approximation

[image: network approximation]

- Big-ip F5 is the ssl end point. The customer have in this device the valid certificate
- IIS redirects by domain to the respective service
- glassfish is the machine with the application (over, of course, a glassfish 3.1)

### How it works

When a user try to connect to _https://somedomain the request arrives to the F5 where the SSL encryption ends; now we have a request to _http://somedomain. In the next step F5 redirects this request to the IIS and this, finally, redirects to glassfish. This petitions are successfully processed.

### Points of interest

- I've full control over glassfish server and S.O. of the vm where it is located. Not other applications are or will be deployed on this server; it's a dedicated server for the app and some services it needs. The Glassfish runs on a VM with a Debian distribution as S.O. This VM is provided by a VM Server but I don't know the  brand, model, etc. The glassfish have the default http listeners configuration.
- I don't have any more information about network and other devices and i can't access to
  any configuration file of any other device. I can't modify any part of the network for my own but maybe ask, suggest or advice for a change. Network's behavior should not change.
- Actually users reach the application without problem.
- The used certificate is a simple domain certificate trusted by Verysign
- The customer have no idea of how to solve this.

### The problem

All the third party WS the application must access have an unique https access and, in some cases, the authentication required is mutual (two-way) and here we find the problem. When the application wants to connect to WS with mutual ssl authentication it sends the glassfish local keystore configuration targeted certificate. Customer wants, if possible, use the same cert for incoming and outcoming secure connections. This cert is in the F5 and i can't add to the glassfish keystore because if I do this I would be breaking Verysign contract requirements. I've been looking for a solution at google, here(stackoverflow), jita,... but only incoming traffic solutions I've found. I understand that maybe a SSL proxy is required but I haven't found any example or alternative solution for the outcoming ssl connections.

## What I'm asking for

I'm not english speaker (isn't obvious?) and maybe i doesn't use the correct terms in my search terms. I can understand that this context can be a nightmare and hard to solve but I will stand... The first think I need is to know if exists a solution (or solutions) for this problem and if it (or they!) exist where or how can I find it/them. I've prepared different alternatives to negotiate with the customer but I need to known the true. I've spent tones of hours on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions.

1)pay verisign more money for a second "license/cert".  They will be happy to take your money for the "privilege".  :)

2)Create a different virtual server listening on 443 which points to a pool that has your client's server address as the pool member.  Then on the virtual server, attach a serverssl profile that is configured to use the same cert you are using for the incoming connections.  Then the F5 would authenticate with the same cert along with your app server would not need a client cert installed.  Also, if they need to initiate a session to you, you would have to setup a virtual server with a clientssl profile that uses the same cert and requires a client cert to connect.

If your destinations may not be static addresses, then an irule(s) would have to be created to deal with that.  Can be handled in 10 or later code with a DNS call in the irule and setting a node for the session to go.